# Excel VBA - Formula with contained variable throwing "not defined" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro where I enter the subtotal for a dynamic range given a filtered list, with the dynamic range being stored as a variable (lastRow2014).  However, I get an Application or Object defined error at the line where I try to create the formula.  I've tried searching online to make sure the syntax is correct and it seems to be.  I've included the relevant code (although there is more earlier, I don't want it to be too long.

```
    'For ATRT, we'll need to vlookup the 2016 data since it's not currently formatted.
    Range("AB11").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Y11,P:U,6,FALSE)"
    Range("AB11").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB11:AB" & lastRow2014)


    'Now, let's calculate the percentage.  The trick will be the reference.
    Range("AA4").Formula = "='Summary 2'!M3" 'This is the index from the summary tab
    Range("AC10").Value = "Within?"
    Range("AC11").Formula = "=IF(AND(Z11 <=(AA11 + ($AA$4 * AA11)), Z11 >= (AA11 - (AA11 * $AA$4))), ""WITHIN"", ""NOT"")"
    Range("AC11").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC11:AC" & lastRow2014)
    'Let's test this first before we continue.  This will all help us get the Filters for "Within"?  Dynamically based on the filter entry.
    'From here we'll get the ATRT, counts, etc.


    'For TOTAL data, we will make sure the filters are set.  Wait... I think this only applies to SHARED.

    Range("A10").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="1"
     Range("A10").AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:= _
        "WITHIN"

    'ATRT 2014
   Range("U5").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,Z11:Z & ""lastRow2014"")"
   Range("V5").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,J11:J & ""lastRow2014"")"
   Range("U6").Formula = "=V5/U5"
```

Comment: This `Range("U5").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,Z11:Z & ""lastRow2014"")"` should've been this `Range("U5").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,Z11:Z" & lastRow2014 &")"` and use `Debug.Print lastRow2014` to check what is the value of that varibale

Comment: Try `Range("U5").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,Z11:Z" & lastRow2014 &")"